# What does "e chi te molla" mean in dialetto Romano?

Tags: meaning, regional

And is it just dialect or does it have a meaning in standard Italian? If so, is it the same meaning or does it have another meaning? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @Lina!

Comment: This means I will beg you in language near I live

Comment: @Titi: Welcome to Italian.SE! Unfortunately this does not seem to answer the question. Do you live near Rome? The question is explicitly about the usage there. Moreover since it contradicts the other answers and my experience it would be nice if you could elaborate a bit more about the meaning, maybe adding a few examples.

Comment: @Titi: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/2974)

Answer (score 10):

This phrase is used to express esteem, admiration and respect to a person.
Literally it means that no one can even think to leave that person's company.
The verb *mollare* in this case has the meaning of "to leave someone".
In Italian the correct preposition is *ti*, instead of *te*, that is dialetto romano.  So in Italian you could say "e chi ti molla?".

Other similar forms are "e chi te molla più!" o "chi te molla a te!".

Comment: Although I'm from Rome, I didn't know that this is an idiomatic expression. It seems to me that it's more slang than dialect.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with the comment above. I just want to provide a different context for the sentence. For example, you could say it also for a situation, not only for a person:

"Ho trovato un **lavoro** vicino a casa, che mi piace e in cui guadagno tantissimo. E chi **lo** molla più?" -->  here it means: I will try all my best to stay and work there. I am not intentioned to leave this work, because I like it very much.

Or, for a person:

"La mia **ragazza** è intelligente e anche stupenda. E chi **la** molla?" --> I like very much my girlfriend and I don't want us to be parted.

As you can see, "*Mollare*" means "lasciare", "leave".

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to add the origin of the expression. It doesn't come from `molla` as a noun (which means spring, coil), but from `molle` as an adjective (which means soft, squishy or soaked). From this is derived the immediate and true correct meaning of the verb `mollare`, which is a synonym to `allentare` and means slacken, loose. From this, and the idea of loosening a rope or slackening a knot, comes the figurative expression of letting something go, lose the grasp or something, or desist.

Also note that the verb `mollare` is much more used than the strictly correct `lasciare` in current speaking, but you should never use it in any formal context, as it is a rather colloquial and almost slangy term.